# grep part of nth lines linux

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have a file like:

```
something1

something2 201101130000

thing

thing1

thing2

AAA, -2, 4, 0, 54;

thing3

thing4

AAA, 43, 43, 0, 5, 0, 0,;

thing5

AAA, 132.0, 43.0,  0.0,  0.0, 43.0,210.0,'

thing5
```

How to copy the date (201101130000) from the second line, add a comma (,) then put the numbers of the line before last (132,0, 43.0,  0.0, 43.0, 210.0) in newfile.txt
the new file should look like:(the original file does not have spaces between lines as it is here)

```
20110113, 132.0, 43.0,  0.0,  0.0, 43.0,210.0
```

I tried grep and sed with no luck. Thanks for your help

Comment: awk? show what you've attempted, and we'll try help fixing that, but we're not going to just bang out some code for you.

Comment: awk 'FNR==2 {print $2} FNR==11 {print $2}' *myfile.txt > test.txt as I have many files that I want to process. I face two problems here. The first is it prints FNR==2 on a line and FNR==11 on a line below it. The second problem is my 11th line sometimes starts with 3 digits (as per my exampl) and sometimes starts like AAA, 0.0,210.0, 23.0, 0.0,; In other words I have three blank spaces before the number so my code in this case prints only the first zero while it prints the entire string if AAA had 3digits first (e.g. 120.0 instead of 0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've interpreted your question:

- You're trying to 'grep' and join parts of two lines. These two lines are always the second and second last lines.
- You're also trying to redirect output to another file. You can use [shell redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) for this, like: `awk ... file > outputfile`.

---

---

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed '2h; $!N; $!D; ${ G; s/[^,]*\([^\n]*\).* \([0-9]\{8\}\).*/\2\1/; s/..$// }' file
```

Since you've tagged this as linux, I'm guessing you've got `GNU sed` and don't mind golf:

```
sed -r '2h;$!N;$!D;${G;s/[^,]*([^\n]*).*\s([0-9]{8}).*/\2\1/;s/..$//}' file
```

Results:

```
20110113, 132.0, 43.0,  0.0,  0.0, 43.0,210.0
```

Explanation:

```
2h         # copy the second line to hold space
$!N        # if not the last line append the next line
$!D        # if not the last line delete up to the first newline in the pattern
$ { ... }  # one the last line, perform two substitutions
```

---

---

Alternatively, `awk` may be easier to understand:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { c++; next } FNR==2 { x = substr($NF,0,8) } FNR==c-1 { sub(/[^,]*/,x); sub(/..$/,""); print }' file file
```

Results:

```
20110113, 132.0, 43.0,  0.0,  0.0, 43.0,210.0
```

Explanation:

```
FNR==NR { c++; next }    # read the first file in the arguments list, to get a 
                         # count of the number of lines in the file
FNR==2 { ... }           # when reading the second line of the second file in the
                         # arguments list, take a substring of the last field
FNR==c-1 { ... }         # one the second last line of the second file in the
                         # arguments list, perform two substitutions and print
                         # the line.
```

Comment: awk 'FNR==2 {print $2} FNR==11 {print $2}' *myfile.txt > test.txt as I have many files that I want to process. I face two problems here. The first is it prints FNR==2 on a line and FNR==11 on a line below it. The second problem is my 11th line sometimes starts with 3 digits (as per my exampl) and sometimes starts like AAA,   0.0,210.0, 23.0,  0.0,; In other words I have three blank spaces before the number so my code in this case prints only the first zero while it prints the entire string if AAA had 3digits first (e.g. 120.0 instead of 0.0).

Comment: Steve, you are a genius! I mis-printed your code. It works with one glitch. as yo wrote FNR==2 {..} reads the 2nd line of 2nd file...I want it to start reading from the first file instead.

Comment: @user2031063: That's the thing, the first file _is_ the second file. In my `awk` answer, see that I've listed the file name twice. The file is processed once to get a count of the number of lines (which is necessary to workout where the second last line is), then it's processed a second time to piece together your string. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

`AWK` do the trick:

```
awk '/something[0-9][ ]*[0-9]+/{d = $2;} /AAA/{v = $0;} END{gsub("AAA",d,v); print v;}' file.txt
```

The output is:

```
201101130000, 132.0, 43.0, 0.0, 0.0, 43.0,210.0
```

Comment: thanks 4 ur answer,didn't work.I tried the following: awk 'FNR==2 {print $2} FNR==11 {print $2}' *myfile.txt > test.txt as I have many files that I want to process. I face two problems here. The first is it prints FNR==2 on a line and FNR==11 on a line below it. The second problem is my 11th line sometimes starts with 3 digits (as per my exampl) and sometimes starts like AAA, 0.0,210.0, 23.0, 0.0,; In other words I have three blank spaces before the number so my code in this case prints only the first zero while it prints the entire string if AAA had 3digits first (e.g. 120.0 instead of 0.0).